# MYSQL - lacked sufficient buffer

Tags: windows, mysql, windows-server-2003, mysql5

I'm getting this error on my MYSQL Server `Version is 5.0.4`:

`An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full`

When I restart the server it works normally, but after a time the message return on my applications that are connected to this server.

The server runs the `Windows 2003`.

Best regards,

Comment: Looks like a memory issue but it does not appear to be a bug in MySql bugtracker. You might take a look at your application and make sure it is freeing or clearing variables and memory.

Comment: @apesa Problem solved, was a memory issue like you've said! Thank you.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Please do so to help others. @apesa, you might want to make a complete answer from it as well.

Comment: Glad I could help. @Sven I only had a suggestion as to what the problem could be. I did not have an answer then and do not know what the actual issue was now. So I can't answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a memory problem, I was with some programs consuming a lot of memory. I configure this programs to use less memory and solved the problem with MYSQL.

Best regards,